# Regex difficulties in google mail app script - select word between two words

Tags: javascript, regex, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The script reads the plain text from emails and sends them to another function to write exact values in a spreadsheet.

My problem is to get some data(date, name, etc) from email plain text.

Here is the function:

```
   var threads = GmailApp.search('label:aoaoaoaoa');
   Logger.log(threads);
   Logger.log(threads[0].getMessages());
   Logger.log(threads[0].getMessages().length);
   var messages;// = threads[0].getMessages();
   var ContentEmail;// = messages[0].getBody();

   var bodyRe = new RegExp("(?=start date)(.*)(?=finish date)");

   for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    messages = threads[i].getMessages()
    ContentEmail = messages[0].getPlainBody();

   var myArray = bodyRe.exec(ContentEmail);
   Logger.log(myArray);
```

myArray is null.
I tried many regex notations to get text between two words. Some of them return null. The others caused SyntaxError in the script.

This is an example message that I want to get date, name, tel number, email and place.

```
Confirmation Code: CAXNA3JAA   Tue, October 01, 2013
start date     Tue, October 08, 2013
finish date 
Place: AOA Studio <http://www.**********************>
[image: Ali] <http://www.**********************>
Ali <http://www.***************************>
+49 000 000 00000
******@gmail.com
```

Or do you suggest to use google script html functions to read data from emails? [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message)

Answer (score 0):

If you can specify using multiline you could use the following:

```
^start date\s*(.+)
```

However this doesn't include that find date shows up next.

Otherwise, this worked for me: (you may want to be careful with line breaks)

```
start date\s*(.+)\nfinish date
```

To include `\r` or `\n` you can use:

```
start date\s*(.+)(\r|\n)+finish date
```

Comment: Is there any good regex editor good for google app scripts? I'm using gskinner but it doesn't give same results in google scripts.

Comment: It might be tough - it looks like google has their own flavour of regex called "RE2" - not sure what is out there for testing that.

Comment: @hayzem Apps scripts use standard Javascript RegExp. You should be able to search for an editor that uses them.